# Finding distribution of $g(X,Y)$ given distributions of $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

Let $X,Y$ follow the geometric distribution, with parameters $p_1,p_2$ respectively, and be independent.

$f_X(x)=p_1(1-p_1)^x, \text{if } x=0,1,.. \text{ and } 0 \text{ otherwise}$

and similarly for $Y$

We computed the probabilities

$P(X \ge x)=\frac{p_2}{p_1+p_2-p_1p_2}$ and

$P(X=Y)=\frac{p_1p_2}{p_1+p_2-p_1p_2}$

We want to find the distribution of $min(X,Y)$

If we compute the probability $P(min(X,Y) \ge z)=P(X \ge z, Y \ge z)=P(X \ge z)P(Y \ge z)=(1-p_1)^z(1-p_2)^z=(1-(p_1+p_2-p_1p_2))^z$

we understand that $min(X,Y)$ follows the geometric distibution as well with parameter $p_1+p_2-p_1p_2$

Before doing this, I tried calculating $P(min(X,Y)=z)$ as follows

$$=P((X=z,Y \ge X) or (Y=z,X \ge Y))=P(X=z,Y \ge X)+P(Y=z,X \ge Y)-P(X=Y=z)=P(Y \ge X)+P(X \ge Y)-P(X=Y)=\frac{p_2}{p_1+p_2-p_1p_2}+\frac{p_1}{p_1+p_2-p_1p_2}-\frac{p_1p_2}{p_1+p_2-p_1p_2}=1$$

which is clearly a wrong answer.

The mistake is not done on calculations so I'm most probably doing something wrong on the theoretical part. I can't seem to spot this so any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The equality $=P(X=z,Y\geq X)+P(Y=z,X\geq Y)-P(X=Y=z)$ is okay but the next ($=P(Y\geq X)+P(X\geq Y)-P(X=Y)$) is wrong.

Note that $z$ has disappeared there so the expression is not depending on $z$ anymore. Actually it equals $P(Y\geq X\text{ or }X\geq Y)$ hence of course  equals $1$.

---

If there is a sequences of independent experiments that can succeed (with probability $p_1$) or fail then $X$ can be looked at as the number of failures that preceed the first succes.

If next to that (and independent) there is an another sequence of independent experiments that can succeed (this time with probability $p_2$) or fail then here $Y$ can be looked as the number of failures that preceed the first succes.

Now let's speak of a succes at $n$ if *at least one* the two $n$-th experiments (mentioned above) succeed. That gives another sequence of independent experiments that can succeed or fail. This time with probability $p_1+p_2-p_1p_2$ and evidently $\min(X,Y)$ is in this case the number of failures that preceed the first succes. This makes clear why $\min(X,Y)$ has geometric distribution with parameter $p_1+p_2-p_1p_2$.

Comment: So, just to make it clear, what you meant was, $P(min(X,Y)=z)=P(X=z,Y\geq X)+P(Y=z,X\geq Y)-P(X=Y=z) \ne P(Y\geq X)+P(X\geq Y)-P(X=Y)=P(Y\geq X\text{ or }X\geq Y)=1$, right? So what should the probability be equal to? (By the way thanks for the insight to think about this intuitively)

Comment: It will (of course) equal $r(1-r)^z$ where $r=p_1+p_2-p_1p_2$. I think it is kind of useless to work it out, and I am too lazy for that at the moment. You allready found a nice proof that $\min(X,Y)$ is geometrically distributed. Just one note: in your question it should be mentioned that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.